# TTTAttributedLabel multiple colors

Tags: ios, uikit

I have this code

```
[label setText:@"ddddasdasdas" afterInheritingLabelAttributesAndConfiguringWithBlock:^ NSMutableAttributedString *(NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributedString) {
            [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName value:(id)[UIColor blackColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,1)];
            [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName value:(id)[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(2,3)];
            [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName value:(id)[UIColor greenColor] range:NSMakeRange(5,2)];
            return mutableAttributedString;}];
```

And only the first character change color but the rest of the text is not changing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[mutableAttributedString addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName value:(id)[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,1)];
```

or:

```
[mutableAttributedString addAttribute:(NSString*)NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:(id)[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,1)];
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue was that i need to put .CGRef on each color, my bad